# SYSML- Activity diagram- modeling function calls and return

Tags: uml, modeling, activity-diagram, rhapsody, sysml

I'm new to SysML and modeling in general and this is for the purpose of learning.
I have an activity diagram and multiple calls to a "Call behavior" and would like the calling activity diagram to continue from where it left off, after the Call behavior has finished executing.
I tried using guards, even though that is not exactly accurate, but that did not work for me either.

The left part of the diagram shows a merge node with a control flow to "Verify_And_Map_Data", and the intention is for all three operations to repeat the call behavior in sequence.

The sequence intended is :

- Initialize_Master_Follow_Data
- Verify_And_Map_Data
- Initialize_XOR_Data
- Verify_And_Map_Data
- Initialize_Feedback_Linked_Data
- Validate_Motor_Start_Stop

[image]

Edit: Thanks qwerty_so . How about this one, it pretty much contains the same elements and control flow, exempt for evStartAnimation,, and organized in a top down way.

[Top-Down_Activity Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF4XK.png)

Comment: I'm not in SysML but your AD does in no way look like being ordered in the way the text describes. More like "let's see what elelements we can place on the diagram".

Comment: You need to comment (and the @<name>) to inform me about your edit. Just saw it by coincidence. The top down is the same as the above except you moved the actions.

Comment: Basically you should just place the actions as in the description. `Verify_And_Map_Data` would appear 2 times then (it's a call behavior anyway).

Comment: @qwerty_so Thanks again. 
I thought of calling it multiple times as you described and that may very well be the best representation of the system. Technically when I call it multiple times the software creates instances and that's what threw me off as I want to model a multiple calls of the same function. 
This is pretty much a newbie mistake, I focused too much on the internals of the modeling tool and forgot the model itself. 
Thanks again, very much appreciated.

Comment: ADs are not so much about "real nature" instances. You focus on that in the class design and reflecting it in SDs. This is more the business view.